# How to validate multiple emails in a form?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple emails in my form. I would like to validate each email once I click the SUBMIT button.

```
vm.isEmailInvalid = false;

function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))
  {
    vm.isEmailInvalid = false;
    return (true)
  }
    //alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    vm.isEmailInvalid = true;
    return (false)
}
```

i.QuestionID increases dynamically

```
<input> type = 'text' id="i.QuestionID" required 
ng-model="i.TextBoxAnswers[0]" />

<input> type = 'text' id="i.QuestionID" required  
ng-model="i.TextBoxAnswers[0]" />

<input> type = 'text' id="i.QuestionID" required 
ng-model="i.TextBoxAnswers[0]" />
```

If I have only one Email, it appears to be working.

Say,

1. 1st email is correct.
2. 2nd email is null (message should display Email is required)
3. 3rd email is not null (say test@yahoo)

   (message should display Email is not in a valid format)

Assuming I have only one email

```
<input ng-model="vm.senderEmail"
                           type="text"
                           name="senderEmail"
                           ng-style="vm.SetRequired(true)"
                           placeholder="user@email.com"
                           class="form-control" />
                    <div ng-if="vm.isSubmitClick && vm.isEmailInvalid
                         && vm.senderEmail.length == 0"
                         style="color:red;text-align: left;">
                        Confirmation email is required.
                    </div>                    

                    <div ng-if="vm.isSubmitClick && vm.isEmailInvalid && vm.senderEmail.length > 0 "
                        style="color:red;text-align: left;">
                        Your email address is not in valid format
                    </div>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Your html code is cut and in bad format. Edit it for us, and add JS code how you call `ValidateEmail` function

Comment: @pindev, I have modified the question and let me know if you have enough information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with HTML only:

```html
<form name="form">
  <label>Email:
    <input multiple
           name="email"
           pattern=".+@b.c"
           required
           title="Please provide only a @b.c e-mail address"
           type="email">
  </label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Attribute in used:

- multiple: allow multiple, comma-separated, e-mail addresses to be
  entered.
- pattern: a RegExp the input's contents must match in order
  to be valid.
- required: indicates that the input must have a value
  before the form can be submitted

Ref: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)

Comment: ,the form has multiple fields to enter email address. I have to loop through the form because it is possible to have more than one input field. I create the input field based on the database criteria. So I build the field dynamically.

Comment: Aa I see that :)